# android ListView mListView.getChildAt(i) can't be get, how to solve it?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I created the code below to get the contents of multiple `EditText`:

```
Integer data[] = new Integer[4];

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
for (i=0;i < listView.getCount();i++){
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) listView.getChildAt(i);
    EditText et = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.record_list_edit);
    data[i] = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
}
```

I can successfully use the following code to to get just the first number (or whichever one I want):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) listView.getChildAt(0);
EditText et = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.record_list_edit);
data[0] = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

But when I use the `for` loop to get all, it breaks.

This is the error log:

```
08-28 22:12:33.931 7814-7814/edu.nankai.soar.demof E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: edu.nankai.soar.demof, PID: 7814

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4851)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20016)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5506)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:952)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4851) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20016) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5506) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:952) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747) 
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
   at edu.nankai.soar.demof.SensorsActivity.log(SensorsActivity.java:81)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4851) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20016) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5506) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:952) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
```

Comment: Did you try putting: `int[] data = new int[listView.getCount()];` after initialising your listview?

Comment: Where is the SetAdatper to listview ?. Listview view will be destroyed and  recreated when it is off the screen. So, Use POJO class as List and save the data on to the POJO class.You will get the data from that POJO. like listItem.get(pos).getYourIntStrring(); here POJO class is your common class. List<YourPojoClass> listItems= new ArrayList<>();

Comment: It working!!! Oh!! Really thak you!!

Answer (score 0):

Really thank you， Shaishav

```
Integer data[] = new Integer[listView.getCount()];
```

I know why I was wrong. I I counted the wrong number... I was so stupid...

The answer comes form Shaishav.